# Groups whose complex irreducible representations are finite dimensional

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings

By a *complex irreducible representation* of a group $G$, I mean a simple $\mathbb CG$-module.  So my representations need not be unitary and we are working in the purely algebraic setting.

It is easy to see that any complex irreducible representation of a virtually abelian group is finite dimensional. (Recall that a group is *virtually abelian* if it has a finite index abelian subgroup.)  I believe it was long ago an open question whether the converse is true and essentially I'm interested in the status of this question:

> > Is a group virtually abelian if and only if all its complex irreducible representations are finite dimensional?

Here is what I know about the problem:

1. It was shown by E. Thoma that all irreducible unitary representations of a discrete group are finite dimensional if and only if the group is virtually abelian.  This is, of course, a different category than I am looking at, but relevant.
2. It was shown independently by Snider and Wehrfritz that a solvable group whose complex irreducible representations are all finite dimensional is virtually abelian, cf. [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/groups-whose-irreducible-representations-have-finite-degree-ii/32BFD9869091BBCF0E43F9A9ADCB0CE3). However, it seems that the paper trail grows cold after this, in the sense that these papers don't seem to have many citations on Mathscinet.  I am not sure if this is because they are only cited in old papers that are not recorded in citation part of Mathscinet, of if people stopped working on the problem.
3. If $G$ is a finitely generated group whose irreducible representations are all finite dimensional, then $G$ is residually finite.  This is because $\mathbb CG$ is semiprimitive, which means that it has enough irreducible representations to separate points, and hence $G$ has enough irreducible representations to separate points.  But a theorem of Malcev says a finitely generated linear group is residually finite.  <strike>I don't know if the problem can be reduced to finitely generated groups.</strike>
4. As, @YCor pointed out (and was first observed by Kaplansky) a virtually abelian group has all its complex irreducible representation of bounded degree. Conversely, if $G$ has all its complex irreducible representations of bounded degree, then $G$ is virtually abelian by a result of Isaacs and Passman [see here](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1964-029-5).
5. B. Hartley proved that the question has a positive answer for locally finite groups.
6. Passman and Temple showed that the problem reduces to finitely generated groups and also that if all complex irreducible representations of $G$ are finite dimensional, then $G/N$ is virtually abelian for some finitely generated normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, see [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~passman/finite.pdf).
7. Snider prove that the question has a positive answer for periodic (=torsion) groups.  See [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-12/S0002-9939-06-08438-3/home.html).

I am primarily interested in the case of a countable group.

Comment: Note that a virtually abelian group has all its irreducible representations finite dimensional *of bounded dimension*. So one can also ask about a (weaker) converse of this (stronger) statement. And one can also wonder whether, for any reason, the existence of irreducible representations of arbitrary large dimension might imply the existence of one of infinite dimension (this is not true in the -distinct- context of unitary representations of compact groups).

Comment: @YCor, I did wonder in that direction.  I had hoped something like an ultraproduct of finite dimensional simple modules of unbounded dimension would give an infinite dimensional simple, but the problem seems to be that being simple is not first order in the language of modules over $\mathbb CG$ because you are not allowed to quantify over elements of $\mathbb CG$, which are constants, but only over elements of the module. And I guess the same is true for finite dimensionality?

Comment: @YCor, I answer the first part of your comment in the edited question.

Comment: Yes, the ultraproduct is even of uncountable dimension, so is never (for a countable group) a simple module.

Comment: @YCor,  that is what I suspected.

Comment: To add to the background, if I understand properly, the answer is positive when $G$ is locally finite (B Hartley, 1977).

Comment: @YCor, yes this is proved in Hartley, B.
Injective modules over group rings.
Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 28 (1977), no. 109, 1–29.  I forgot to mention that one, too.  I couldn't find anything else in characteristic 0 after that.

Comment: @YCor,  I found two more recent references by backtracking more carefully from Hartley.  So I guess this likely still an open problem.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the reference to Passman-Temple  "*Groups with All Irreducible Modules of Finite Degree*" yields another important source of examples: the class of groups with only finite-dimensional complex irreps is stable under taking subgroups (Lemma 4(ii)). Thus, if a groups has an infinite-dimensional irrep, so do all its overgroups. In particular, all groups with a subgroup isomorphic to $F_2$ have an $\infty$-di irrep. Combined with the solvable case and the Tits alternative, this shows that linear groups satisfy the conjecture. This paper contains other striking restrictions.

Comment: @YCor, yes that is a good point. Their paper is the best recent reference I found.  They also look at the Tits alternative.

Comment: One paper quoting Passman-Temple (2000) is by Snider (2006); if I understand correctly, it settles the case of torsion groups.

Comment: @YCor that is reference 7 in the updated list of what I know.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the result you mentioned by E. Thoma in 1. ? Thanks.

Comment: @pitariver E. Thoma. Uber unita ̈re Darstellungen abz ̈ahlbarer, diskreter Gruppen. Math. Ann.,
153:111–138, 1964.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Great, thank you!

Comment: Does anybody know anything about the same question for representations over finite fields?

Comment: @MatteoVannacci,  my memory is that some of the papers I mentioned above handle positive characteristic.  I don't remember too well what they say

Comment: Hi Ben: the recent question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430433/irreducibles-of-virtually-abelian-finitely-generated-groups has prompted me to try and look up the proof that "any complex irreducible representation of a virtually abelian group is finite dimensional" and to my embarrassment I'm getting stuck. What argument/source for this result did you have in mind? Something based on PI-rings?

Comment: See https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/8487797A93EB3087FD48DD7468186DD3/S0008414X00028704a.pdf/groups-with-representations-of-bounded-degree.pdf and the Isaacs-Passman paper in the question.  I believe this is in Passman's book too.  It is based on PI stuff.

Comment: Hmm, those are the two papers I have been staring at and I am not 100% sold that they actually prove this. (The Isaacs-Passman paper just says that Kaplansky "essentially proved" this, and investigates converse results; the Kaplansky paper has this detour via primitive representations of the L^1 group algebra and never actually says why inf-dim reps of the group can't be irreducible.) Will try Passman's book

Comment: @YemonChoi try this one https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-54/issue-1/Certain-representations-of-infinite-group-algebras/pjm/1102911458.pdf