# Extreme points of the set of all traces

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, traces

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group with a bound on its complex unitary irreducible representations: That is assume all complex unitary irreducibles of $G$ have degrees at most $k$ for some integer $k$. For example all finite groups and all virtually abelian groups satisfy this constraint. See for example my other question [Irreducibles of virtually abelian finitely generated groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430433/irreducibles-of-virtually-abelian-finitely-generated-groups).

Then by virtue of these finite dimensional irreducibles, we can define traces on the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$: For any irreducible $\rho$ of $G$ we see that $a \mapsto \mathrm{tr}(\rho(a))$ is a trace on $\mathbb{C}[G]$.

By trace I mean any positive linear functional $\tau: \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\tau(ab) = \tau(ba)$ and $\tau(1) = 1$. Let $T$ be the set of all traces on $\mathbb{C}[G]$. We can easily see that $T$ is convex.

If $G$ is finite it is elementary to see that $T$ is a simplex and its finitely many extreme points are exactly the traces coming from the irreducible representations (these are essentially the irreducible characters).

Now if $G$ is not finite can we still say that all extreme points of $T$ are the traces coming from irreducibles of $G$?

Some notes:

- For these special groups $G$, there are many references studying the algebraic properties of $\mathbb{C}[G]$. For example we know this algebra is semiprimitive (i.e., its Jackobson radical is trivial) and semiprime. Note that when $G$ is not finite, $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is not Artinian (hence not semisimple). See the book by Donald Passman "Infinite group rings".
- Any reference that studies properties of group von Neumann algebras or group $C^*$-algebras of these representation bounded groups would be very helpful.

Comment: For virtually abelian groups every irreducible unitary representation in a Hilbert space is finite dimensional and so presumably C*-theory will give you these are the extreme points but I am no expert

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "coming from irreducibles," but Dixmier's C*-algebra book Corollary 6.8.6 *probably* has what you're looking for.  For any C*-algebra $A$ a trace $\tau$ is extreme if and only if the GNS representation $\pi_\tau$ associated with it is a factor representation.  The GNS representation $\pi_\tau$ won't be irreducible in general but the C*-algebra generated by it will be isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ in your specific case

Comment: Thank you Benjamin and Caleb. @CalebEckhardt a few questions. In the meantime, I am trying to read through Diximier's book. Would this $n$ in your answer be bounded by $k$? $k$ is the bound on the degree of irreducibles. And why would the GNS representation be a type I factor in the case of these special groups? Finally, can we be sure $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: CG is not a C*-algebra if G is infinite but it can be completed to one and I think in the virtually abelian case you should get the same traces.  In the virtually abelian case the universal and reduced C*-algebras are the same.

Comment: @user3826143 Yes, $n$ is bounded by $k.$ If a factor is infinite dimensional then it has an infinite dimensional irreducible representation hence the only choice in your case is a finite dimensional factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this as a long comment for your reference request about the group $C^{\ast}$-algebra and the group von-Neumann algebra.
Let $G$ be a locally compact group. It is common to denote
the group $C^{\ast}$-algebra by $C^{\ast}(G)$,
the reduced group $C^{\ast}$-algebra by $C_r^{\ast}(G)$,
the Fourier algebra by $A(G)$,
the Fourier-Stieltjes algebra by $B(G)$,
the group von Neumann algebra by $VN(G)$, and
the enveloping group von Neumann algebra by $W^{\ast}(G)$.

It is well known that $W^{\ast}(G) = (B(G))^{\ast}$, $B(G) = (C^{\ast}(G))^{\ast}$, $VN(G) = (A(G))^{\ast}$ as Banach spaces, e.g., please see the book by Kaniuth and Lau https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-231 .

Next, a von Neumann algebra $M$ is type I finite if and only if its predual $M_{\ast}$ has the Dunford-Pettis property, pls. see Lemma 1 in [Hamana1977](http://doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178240703) and Proposition 5.1 in [OikhbergSpinu2015](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/bdu102) .

Also, the following are equivalent for any $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$.

- $i.$ $A^{\ast\ast}$ is a finite type I von Neumann algebra.
- $i'.$ $A^{\ast\ast}$ is a finite von Neumann algebra.
- $ii.$ $A^{\ast}$ has the Dunford-Pettis property.
- $iii.$ $A$ has no infinite dimensional irreducible representations.
- $iv.$ $A$ has the Dunford-Pettis property.

$(i\Leftrightarrow i'\Leftrightarrow ii\Leftrightarrow iii)$ Theorem 1 in [Hamana1977](http://doi.org/10.2748/tmj/1178240703) and [Bunce1992](http://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1992-1091177-1).
$(iii\Leftrightarrow iv)$ see Corollary 5.4 in [OikhbergSpinu2015](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/bdu102).

---

We can simply take $M=VN(G)$ and $A=C^{\ast}(G)$, $A=C^{\ast}_r(G)$ above. For instance, the following theorem is from [LauÜlger1993](http://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1993-1147402-7).
[image]

If we also assume that every unitary representation of $G$ is atomic, or the regular representation is atomic, then we can say more, please see [Taylor1983](http://doi.org/10.1007/BF01455310) and [LauÜlger1993](http://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1993-1147402-7).

Comment: This is incredible! I cannot thank you enough

Comment: @user3826143 thank you for your kind words, I'm glad if you find it useful.